# How can I get Ubuntu to work with Radeon R9 390?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I am running 17.10, and struggling to get my graphics card working. The GUI continues to have graphical artefacts  and screen tearing. Worst of all after a few minutes the GUI crashes and the screen turns black. I have followed several sets of instructions designed to fix problems for Radeon Hawaii cards and none have had ANY impact on the issues.

I have:

- disabled radeon and used amdgpu driver instead.
- switched from display port to hdmi.
- tried other kernels.

Here is the output of `lspci -k`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390] (rev 80)
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

I have tried various solutions from questions like these [I think I'm using radeon instead of amdgpu? How do I change?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927601/i-think-im-using-radeon-instead-of-amdgpu-how-do-i-change).

Should I give up on Ubuntu (or Linux in general), or is there an effective way to get this card working?

Comment: Crossposted to U&L as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427527/graphics-cards-in-linux

Comment: Well, it's closed there (although it has an upvote so won't be deleted), so if cross-posting is the reason for voting to close this post, then presumably it should not be closed since we only need to close a maximum of one of two cross-posted posts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success following this post:
https://community.amd.com/thread/220560
specifically, installing [dpm query](https://github.com/illwieckz/dpm-query/) seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: Please could you add the steps that worked for you to your post? A link to a tutorial is not considered a sufficient answer here.