# Use integrated graphics instead of video card

Tags: graphics

Is there some way to tell linux to use my integrated graphics card instead of the gpu? The monitor is plugged in to the gpu since I use the same computer to play games on windows however getting this graphics card to work on linux seems impossible. When I boot into recovery mode for example the computer uses integrated graphics and I have a pretty decent experience (although it only allows 4:3 aspect ration and 1600:1200 max pixels). Is there some command that will make the system use the integrated graphics?

EDIT: Adding brand and model number of hardware:

- XFX R9 390 (spent several days trying to get it to work with ubuntu but it has been an epic fail).
- Gigabyte H97 Extreme Gaming Motherboard
- Intel i5-4590
- ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @dsstorefile let me know if I missed anything

Answer (score 0):

Try out the inxi utility. Simply run `inxi -xsGI` and you'll get some very detailed stats. An alternative is to use `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to determine the active graphics driver.

I've had issues on Ubuntu with the R9 390 model specifically. Make sure you're using the latest open source drivers from the Padoka PPA, and a recent version of `linux-firmware`. PPA usage is a hard requirement for proper graphics support on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm running kernel 4.15 newest padoka and using either radeon or amdgpu driver and it doesn't work. The fact its this hard is mind blowing.

Comment: You may want to try installing Solus OS instead. I've had much better luck with AMD hardware on Solus.

Comment: It's not debian though is it?

Comment: It's not based on Debian, which is a good thing, because the Debian architecture is majorly flawed. Solus is written from scratch and has a superior packaging format, with a large software repository that rivals Debian's, and contains better versions of packages (MPV with Vapoursynt, Wine with Gallium Nine, native Steam runtime, etc.), and more modern applications which remain unpackaged for Debian.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010827/will-ubuntu-work-with-radeon-r9-390 got my card working :)

Comment: Nice thing about Solus is that Ikey ensures that all of this is configured out of the box so that no hardware is left behind & needs special tweaking.