# Second Moniter not properly detected, stuck in mirrored

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, vga

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, so I'm going to need a little bit of hand holding.  I've searched this problem and have tried  a few things.

First, some information.  I have a dual-booted computer with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.  I have two moniters, one that is connected with a HDMI cable and one that is connected with VGA.  My graphics card is a Radeon R9 290/390.

On Windows 10 I have no problems with this, but when I boot up in Ubuntu, the moniters are stuck in mirrored mode, showing me the same thing twice.  When I try to change this it doesn't seem to acknowledge the moniters as separate.

I have tried uplugging each moniter and individually both are detected, as I can use either one.  But when I plug in the second one, I don't see a new moniter showing up as an option.

I have installed ARandR and it has not helped, it still only detects the one.  I have searched this problem and have found others with the same problem, but have yet to find a solution that has worked.

Comment: I don't have a Ubuntu 16.04 (2016-April release) around which uses the Unity desktop, but this may be handy - https://ubuntu-manual.org/  I would pull up the menu and type 'disp' (start of word display) and select display.settings, and ensure you don't have mirror enabled.  If you can't find it there, I'd install `unity-tweak-tool`  (has a load of options that aren't available in settings). Sorry it's been too long since I used that release for me to provide more.

Comment: I definitely do not have mirror selected.  In fact, it's a grayed out option because the system is not even acknowledging there are two montiers (despite content appearing on both).  It's basically treating the two screens as one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll have the best luck having both monitors plugged in at boot, vs plugging and unplugging the live system.  I'm not sure it's related, but have you taken a  look at the [recommended Radeon R9 390 kernel parameters](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#R9_390_series_Poor_Performance_and/or_Instability)?  Do you have any other kernel parameters set?  For example, `nomodeset` will break `amdgpu`, [as noted here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#Loading).

In doing some research on the Radeon R9 390, I'm seeing people having the best luck using Kernel >=4.16.7.  At the time of this post, Ubuntu 16.04 mainline does not have this available.  You can see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support) that by upgrading to 18.04, you'd be able to get on 4.15, which is close but not exactly right.  People are also mentioning that `amdgpu` isn't always being used or loaded properly.  You can look at the output of `lspci -k`, find your graphics card, and make sure that `amdgpu` is being used.

There are very detailed instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics) walkthrough of options for Ubuntu 16.04 and an explanation for some of the quirks.  [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927601/i-think-im-using-radeon-instead-of-amdgpu-how-do-i-change) talks about moving from `radeon` to `amdgpu`.  [Some have had success by simply blacklisting `radeon`](https://askubuntu.com/a/927880/13247).

Which drivers do you have running, and which do you want running?  Have you looked at "Additional Drivers", or `ubuntu-drivers devices`.  Can you edit your question and include which drivers are in use?  Is upgrading to 18.04 an option for you?

Comment: So I upgraded to 18.04,  I upgraded the kernal to the newest version, and i applied the reccomended kernal parameters.

Unfortunately, it seems to have made the problem a bit worse overall.  After updating to 18.04, I'm now experiencing quite a bit lof lag in everything I do.  Even just moving the mouser around.  It got a bit better after updating the kernal, but still now like it was before.  And the moniters are still not dual screen as of yet.