# Change Graphics Driver From Intel To AMD in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I want to use AMD Graphics which is dedicated in my HP laptop.
In Ubuntu 18.04 default Intel graphics is used.

[image]

When I execute the command:

```
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
```

it shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [8086:1916] (rev 07)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] [1002:6660] (rev 83)
```

Please let me know how to change it from intel to AMD.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in Ubuntu 20.4 LTS version after a long research. My laptop model is Dell 17 Inspiron 5759 having hybrid graphics card, i.e) integrated Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] and dedicated/discrete AMD Radeon R5 M335 GPU.

Run this command in the terminal and post the results in the question.

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
```

Please refer to the image link below for the results of my laptop.

[My lspci cmd results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnvEQ.png)

I faced problem when using preinstalled radeon driver instead of using amdgpu which is also preinstalled. So I turned off the radeon driver by following the method in this answer: [I think I'm using radeon instead of amdgpu? How do I change?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927601/i-think-im-using-radeon-instead-of-amdgpu-how-do-i-change/1003701#1003701). After that, reboot your laptop and follow this answer: [ATI/Intel hybrid graphics 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761091/ati-intel-hybrid-graphics-16-04-lts/761915#761915). You can check whether your Radeon graphics card is enabled by running the command (from [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-ckiKQotNw&list=PLq7piU2Y6Jph88St33A-FG_ogQjpzVBQi&index=3)):

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
```

Please feel free to post your doubts and let me know if you have been successful. It took me two days to understand what I'm doing, and I have been successful.

Also check [this thread on the Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=278244) too.